# Connecting 3 monitors to stationary Windows PC

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, gpu

I am using:

- CPU: i5 4460
- ram: 16gb ddr3
- GPU: r9 270x

I would like to connect my PC to 3 displays simultaneously, 2 LG PC monitors and a Toshiba LCD TV. Currently, I am only able to connect 2 displays simultaneously: if I turn off the TV, the 2 monitors work and if I unplug one of the monitors the second monitor and the TV will work. When I connect all 3 monitors at the same time, my PC just ignores one of the monitors. I tried using a combination of VGA, DVI, and HDMI to connect and one using 2 DVI and HDMI, all with the same effect. Is it possible to get all monitors working at the same time?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  What version of the operating?

Comment: Use a DVI-DisplayPort adapter for one of the monitors.

Comment: What resolution are the monitors? Have you checked the specs of the card and confirmed your monitors are not exceeding those?

Comment: I am using windows 10, all monitors are are full HD, I also tried  DVI-DisplayPort same effect